# Add Buttons to Dynamically to Layout

Tags: android

When add button to layouts fill _parent occurred add in new line.

That is depending text in the button; one row contains two buttons and one row contains three buttons.

Comment: Please read about LinearLayout, TableLayout, RelativeLayout...

Comment: First describe your question clearly so anybody can at least try once.

Comment: Post query clearly and xml code.

Comment: The best thing is just post your xml file.

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand from your question i tried this.

```
if(button.getText().equals("two"))
{
//call this function.
addButtons(2);
}
```

// inside the function

```
public void addButtons(int n) {
final RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.rel);

for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    final Button btn = new Button(this);
    rl.addView(btn); 
    btn.setText("hello");
    btn.setWidth(320);
    btn.setHeight(40);
}
}
```